# Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: c, stack, linked-list

Lately I have been making my project for stacking, but I have a problem with my code for pushing a node:

```
void push(struct stackNode *Stackptr , int data)
{
     struct stackNode *conductor;

     conductor = malloc(sizeof(struct stackNode));
     if(conductor !=NULL)
     {
                conductor->data=data;
                conductor->nxt=*Stackptr;
                Stackptr = conductor ;
                  }     
     else{
         printf("Wrong insertion"); 
          }

     }
```

But it won't compile. If you want to see the rest of my code here it is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct stackNode
{
       int data;
       struct stackNode *nxt;
       };

struct stackNode *Stack;


void instructions()
{
     printf("        Please Select a Number to do the following\n\n");
     printf("              [1]Push a value\n");
     printf("              [2]Pop a value\n");
     printf("              [2]Peek a node\n");
     printf("              [3]Display\n");
     printf("              [4]Exit\n               ");
     }

     int main ()
     {
         int value; 
         int choice;
         Stack = NULL;

         instructions();

     do
     {
       scanf("%d",&choice);
         system("cls");


         if(choice == 1)
             {
                 printf("Enter your Desired Digit: ");

                                       }

              if(choice == 2)
              {
                        printf(" "); 
                        }       
              if(choice == 3)
              {

                        printf(" ");
                        }
                if(choice == 4 )
                {

                          printf("bye!");
                          return 0;
                          }      



         }while(choice !=4);

         getch();
         }

    void push(struct stackNode *Stackptr , int data)
    {
         struct stackNode *conductor;

         conductor = malloc(sizeof(struct stackNode));
         if(conductor !=NULL)
         {
                    conductor->data=data;
                    conductor->nxt=*Stackptr;
                    Stackptr = conductor ;
                      }     
         else{
             printf("Wrong insertion"); 
              }

         }
```

Comment: No that's not it. What is the compile error?

Comment: What errors is the compiler throwing out when you say it won't compile?

Comment: Can we have some more information? Like the compiler error your receiving perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

In the push function you are assigning a stacknode, and not a pointer to a stacknode.

Here is the error:

```
test.c:76:31: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct stackNode *’ from type ‘struct stackNode’
```

Removing the * assigns the pointer, which is what you want.

So this works:

```
conductor->nxt=Stackptr;
```

However, there are other issues with the program.

Comment: This just fixes the error, but you should really trace your program and be sure you are aware what you are doing with the Stackptr.

Comment: I got this from a book but it's in typedef, so I tried to recode it without typedef but this errors, but I suddenly saw this error soo what's wrong  what should I fix? what are the other issues?

Comment: The push function takes a stack pointer as a parameter, which is the memory location representing the stack. When you push a new node, you assign its 'nxt' pointer to point to the top of the stack, and then the stack pointer is changed to point to the new node that was pushed. There are many examples of this, I would recommend searching around for linked lists in C to get a better understanding. This particular error can be fixed by just not dereferencing the pointer which is assigned to nxt. The * dereferences the pointer and accesses the stacknode itself, you just want to access the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give a quick run-through of finding the fault;
Quick compile, error is;

```
74: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct stackNode *’ from type ‘struct stackNode’
```

Right, so now I know to have a look at line 74.
Down on line 74 is;

```
  conductor->nxt=*Stackptr;
```

Without even having to think out the problem or even get your head around pointers (which you need to, but this is just a quick debug)
So lets remove the * and change it to;

```
  conductor->nxt=Stackptr;
```

And thats one problem sorted.
There are many others within this code though. Make sure you debug and test frequently, and have a go at interpreting the errors. If all else fails, make sure you post a question on here with the error.

Comment: what are the other error?, when I saw this code it's in on typedef so I changed it and recode it without using typedef since it confuses me .

Answer (score 0):

Since you are changing `Stackptr` in the `push` method you need to make this change visible to the caller of `push` by either

- returning the changed `Stackptr` or
- passing the address of `Stackptr`.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
conductor->nxt=*Stackptr;
```

looks wrong. The `nxt` field should be a pointer, but you're de-referencing so you're trying to stuff the entire node in there.

There are many other issues with the code, but this was the first obvious compile-time error I saw.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier if you use `typedef`:

```
typedef struct _stacknode
{
    int data;
    struct _stacknode *nxt;
} StackNode;

StackNode *Stack;
```

Also, as it seems you are learning "C" in the process, check some finished stack implementation. It's quite a common example in programming books or online tutorials. Probably there are tons of them in [github](http://github.com). Study it, then try your own.